# Flex 4: VideoDisplay can play MP3 files?

Tags: apache-flex, mp3, videodisplay

Is it possible to play MP3 files using the VideoDisplay or VideoPlayer components?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes they can play MP3 files. I've just got it working by simply passing the path of the MP3 to a VideoPlayer component instance.

Although I wouldn't recommend using a video component to solely play audio files, I agree that it's sometimes appropriate to play a sound file in a video display component. In my case I have a mixed list of audio and video media items and want a unified preview area and playback/scrub controls.

Comment: Yeah so do I. Thanks, I hope it works in 4.5 as well, I remember trying after no response here and it didn't work.

Comment: Must be a new 4.5 thing then. I'm using 4.5.1.

Comment: Yeah, 4.5.1 I meant. I'll give it another go soon.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a *video* component to play a *sound* file?  Either way, you should probably google before posting here.  This is how you do it:

```
var snd:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("smallSound.mp3"));
snd.play();
```

Comment: I want the controls as well and the video component for the site I need it to play sound is already drawn and all that. SO, can it play MP3 files is still the question. Thanks.

Comment: Not unless their in the same stream.